# remove xml-generated polygons on high zoom level

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, zooming, polygon

I have a page at http://www.noosawaters.org/Google/noosawaters_xml.html with two polygons which I want to remove at a higher zoom level. The polygons are generated from coords held in a mySQL DB table. php creates the necessary xml tree.

My code, though, removes only one of the polygons:

```
var phpscript = "noosawaters_xml.php"; // creates xml data for polygons
downloadUrl(phpscript, function(data) {
var polygons = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("polygon");
for (var a = 0; a < polygons.length; a++) {
   var strokeColor = polygons[a].getAttribute("strokeColor");
   var strokeOpacity = polygons[a].getAttribute("strokeOpacity");
   var strokeWeight = polygons[a].getAttribute("strokeWeight");
   var fillColor = polygons[a].getAttribute("fillColor");
   var fillOpacity = polygons[a].getAttribute("fillOpacity");
   var pts = [];
   var points = polygons[a].getElementsByTagName("point");
   for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      pts[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")));
   }

   var polyOptions = {
      paths: pts,
      strokeColor: strokeColor,
      strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity,
      strokeWeight: strokeWeight,
      fillColor: fillColor,
      fillOpacity: fillOpacity
   }
   var this_polygon = a + 1;
   var NoosaWaters = "NoosaWaters" + this_polygon;
   NoosaWaters = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
   NoosaWaters.setMap(map);
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
      if (map.getZoom() > 18){
         NoosaWaters.setMap(null);
      }
      else{
         NoosaWaters.setMap(map);
      }
   });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways, I prefer the following:

create a custom property for the map, that holds the map-property for the polygons(the Maps-instance or null, depending on the zoom-level):

```
 //add this code right after the code where you create the Maps-instance

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
   var polymap=this.getZoom() > 18 ? null : this;
      if(this.get('polymap')!==polymap){
        this.set('polymap',polymap);
       }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'idle',function(){
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'zoom_changed')
  });
```

The map now has a `polymap`-property which will be updated on `zoom_changed`.

All you have to do now is to bind the map-property of the polygons to the polymap-property of the map,

replace this code :

```
NoosaWaters.setMap(map);
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
      if (map.getZoom() > 18){
         NoosaWaters.setMap(null);
      }
      else{
         NoosaWaters.setMap(map);
      }
   });
```

by that code:

```
NoosaWaters.bindTo('map',map,'polymap');
```